# Using mapply() or any of its family members to call a function over vectors

Tags: r, apply, lapply, mapply

I have a function that has several vector and non vector arguments:

```
   myfun <- function( number , vector1, vector2, number2) {
      # test function thanks to Chi Pak
      temp <- number * vector1 + max(vector2) * number2
      return(temp)
   }
```

I want to perform the following actions:

1. Call this function for a vector of `number`, `numberS`.
2. For each number above I want it to be called with one of each `vector1` obtained from the list `listofvectors1`.
3. `vector2` and `number2` are the same for each call.

In order to clarify it a bit more, this is what I would do with loops:

```
numberS <- c(1,2,3)
listofvectors1 <- list(c(1,2,3), c(5,6,7,8), c(0,1) ) # Obviously has the same length as numberS
vector2 <- c(0.5,3,1)
number2 <- 3.14

for (i in 1:length(numberS)){
   myfun(numberS[i], listofvectors1[[i]], vector2, number2)
}
```

I want to do this using a function like `apply()`, I have been trying using `mapply()` but I can't make it work, as it either nests all the vectors or simply doesn't nest anything.

Comment: Apply functions focus on the return object not simply an iteration method like `for` loops. Please describe more what function does (i.e., desired output).

Comment: @D1X please consider accepting any of the answers below if they were helpful to you by clicking on the check mark to the left. This lets the community know that that answer worked for you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `MoreArgs` argument to specify those arguments you *don't* want to vectorise over.

```
mapply(myfun, NumberS, listofvectors1, MoreArgs=list(vector2, number2))
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Reproducible example

A test `myfun` function

```
myfun <- function( number , vector1, vector2, number2) {
      temp <- number * vector1 + max(vector2) * number2
      return(temp)
   }
```

Your values

```
numberS <- c(1,2,3)
listofvectors1 <- list(c(1,2,3), c(5,6,7,8), c(0,1) ) # Obviously has the same length as numberS
vector2 <- c(0.5,3,1)
number2 <- 3.14
```

You can use `lapply` like this

```
lapply(1:length(numberS), function(x) myfun(numberS[x], listofvectors1[[x]], vector2, number2))

# [[1]]
# [1] 10.42 11.42 12.42
# etc
```

Or `purrr::map2` like this

```
library(purrr)
map2(numberS, listofvectors1, ~myfun(.x, .y, vector2, number2))

# [[1]]
# [1] 10.42 11.42 12.42
# etc
```